# How to make a wrapper Apex class for LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

From another question i created about LWC where i am using multiple wire services, someone told me to make an anonymous APEX class to avoid using 20 wire services.

Since i'm new about LWC i don't really know how to realize this.

**Here is my syntheseComponent.cls :**

```
public with sharing class SyntheseController {
    // Permet de compter le nombre de contact pour la page account
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getContact(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)contact FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Integer countContact = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('contact');
        return countContact;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunity(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunity FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Integer countOpportunity = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunity');
        return countOpportunity;
    }

    // Permet de récuperer la date de la dernière opportunitée de type B2B crée
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static String getLastCreatedOpportunity(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT MAX(CreatedDate)lastCreatedOpportunity FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Datetime lastCreatedOpportunity = (Datetime)groupedResults[0].get('lastCreatedOpportunity');
        String lastCreatedOpportunityFormated = lastCreatedOpportunity.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
        return lastCreatedOpportunityFormated;
    }

    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité de type B2B pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityB2B(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityB2B FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true];
        Integer countOpportunityB2B = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2B');
        return countOpportunityB2B;
    }
    // Permet de récuperer la date de la dernière opportunitée de type B2B crée
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static String getLastCreatedOpportunityB2B(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT MAX(CreatedDate)lastCreatedOpportunityB2B  FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true];
        Datetime lastCreatedOpportunityB2B = (Datetime)groupedResults[0].get('lastCreatedOpportunityB2B');
        String lastCreatedOpportunityB2BFormated = lastCreatedOpportunityB2B.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
        return lastCreatedOpportunityB2BFormated;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité B2B Abonnement pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityB2BAbonnement(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityB2BAbo FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true AND ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c != null];
        Integer countOpportunityB2BAbo = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BAbo');
        return countOpportunityB2BAbo;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité B2B Places Sèches pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityB2BPlacesSeches FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true AND ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c = null];
        Integer countOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BPlacesSeches');
        return countOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montat des opportunités B2B
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityB2BAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityB2BAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true];
        Decimal amountOpportunityB2B = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BAmount');
        return amountOpportunityB2B;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montat des opportunités B2B pour les Abonnements
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityB2BAboAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityB2BAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true AND ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c != null];
        Decimal amountOpportunityB2B = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BAmount');
        return amountOpportunityB2B;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montat des opportunités B2B pour les Places Sèches
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true AND ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c = null];
        Decimal amountOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount');
        return amountOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montant de toutes les opportunités pour un compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Decimal amountOpportunity = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityAmount');
        return amountOpportunity;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité de type Event pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityEvent(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityEvent FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_event__c = true];
        Integer countOpportunityEvent = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityEvent');
        return countOpportunityEvent;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montant des opportunités de type Event
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityEventAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityEventAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_event__c = true];
        Decimal amountOpportunityEvent = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityEventAmount');
        return amountOpportunityEvent;
    }
    // Permet de récuperer la date de la dernière opportunitée de type Even crée
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static String getLastCreatedOpportunityEvent(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT MAX(CreatedDate)lastCreatedOpportunityEvent  FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_event__c = true];
        Datetime lastCreatedOpportunityEvent = (Datetime)groupedResults[0].get('lastCreatedOpportunityEvent');
        String lastCreatedOpportunityEventFormated = lastCreatedOpportunityEvent.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
        return lastCreatedOpportunityEventFormated;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité de type Lagardère pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityLagardere(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityLagardere FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_Lagardere__c = true];
        Integer countOpportunityLagardere = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityLagardere');
        return countOpportunityLagardere;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montant des opportunités de type Lagardère
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityLagardereAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityLagardereAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_Lagardere__c = true];
        Decimal amountOpportunityLagardere = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityLagardereAmount');
        return amountOpportunityLagardere;
    }
    // Permet de récuperer la date de la dernière opportunitée de type Lagardère crée
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static String getLastCreatedOpportunityLagardere(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT MAX(CreatedDate)lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere  FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_Lagardere__c = true];
        Datetime lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere = (Datetime)groupedResults[0].get('lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere');
        String lastCreatedOpportunityLagardereFormated = lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
        return lastCreatedOpportunityLagardereFormated;
    }
    // Permet de compter les activités en cours pour le Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpenActivities(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Subject)openactivities FROM Task WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Integer countOpenactivities = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('openactivities');
        return countOpenactivities;
    }
}
```

**My syntheseComponent.js :**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContact from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getContact';

import getOpportunityAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityAmount';
import getOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunity';
import getLastCreatedOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getLastCreatedOpportunity';

import getOpportunityB2B from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2B';
import getLastCreatedOpportunityB2B from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getLastCreatedOpportunityB2B';
import getOpportunityB2BAbonnement from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BAbonnement';
import getOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches';
import getOpportunityB2BAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BAmount';
import getOpportunityB2BAboAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BAboAmount';
import getOpportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount';

import getOpportunityEvent from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityEvent';
import getOpportunityEventAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityEventAmount';
import getLastCreatedOpportunityEvent from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getLastCreatedOpportunityEvent';

import getOpportunityLagardere from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityLagardere';
import getOpportunityLagardereAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityLagardereAmount';
import getLastCreatedOpportunityLagardere from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getLastCreatedOpportunityLagardere';

import getOpenActivities from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpenActivities';

export default class SyntheseComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getContact, { accId: '$recordId'}) contacts;

    @wire(getOpportunity, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunity;
    @wire(getOpportunityAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityAmount;
    @wire(getLastCreatedOpportunity, { accId: '$recordId'}) lastCreatedOpportunity;

    @wire(getOpportunityB2B, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2B;
    @wire(getLastCreatedOpportunityB2B, { accId: '$recordId'}) lastCreatedOpportunityB2B;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BAbonnement, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BAbo;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BPlacesSeches;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BAmount;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BAboAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BAboAmount;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount;

    @wire(getOpportunityEvent, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityEvent;
    @wire(getOpportunityEventAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityEventAmount;
    @wire(getLastCreatedOpportunityEvent, { accId: '$recordId'}) lastCreatedOpportunityEvent;

    @wire(getOpportunityLagardere, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityLagardere;
    @wire(getOpportunityLagardereAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityLagardereAmount;
    @wire(getLastCreatedOpportunityLagardere, { accId: '$recordId'}) lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere;

    @wire(getOpenActivities, { accId: '$recordId' }) openactivities;
}
```

**And my syntheseComponent.html :**

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Synthèse" icon-name="standard:entitlement">
    <lightning-tabset>
      <lightning-tab label="Général">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <article class="slds-tile slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__body">
              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Contacts">Nb Contacts:</dt>
                  <dd id="contactsId" class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate contactsId" title="Description for first label"><b>{contacts.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opportunités">Nb Opportunités:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunity.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant">Montant Opportunités:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Open Activities">Open Activities:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{openactivities.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Date dernière opp">Dernière Opportunité:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{lastCreatedOpportunity.data}</b></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </lightning-tab>
      <lightning-tab label="Opp B2B" title="2nd tab extended title">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <article class="slds-tile slds-media">
              <div class="slds-media__body">
                <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                  <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp B2B">Nb Opp B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for first label"><b>{opportunityB2B.data}</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant Opp B2B">Montant Opp B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Date derniere opp B2B">Dernière Opp B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{lastCreatedOpportunityB2B.data}</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp B2B Abo">Nb Opp Abo B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BAbo.data}</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant opp abo B2B">Montant Opp Abo B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BAboAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp B2B PS">Nb Opp Places Sèches B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BPlacesSeches.data}</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant opp PS B2B">Montant Opp Places Sèches B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                  </dl>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
      </lightning-tab>
      <lightning-tab label="Opp Event">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <article class="slds-tile slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__body">
              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp Event">Nb Opp Event:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for first label"><b>{opportunityEvent.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant Opp Event">Montant Opp Event:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityEventAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Date derniere opp Event">Dernière Opp Event:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{lastCreatedOpportunityEvent.data}</b></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </lightning-tab>
      <lightning-tab label="Opp Lagardère">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <article class="slds-tile slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__body">
              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp Lagardere">Nb Lagardère:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for first label"><b>{opportunityLagardere.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant Opp Lagardere">Montant Opp Lagardère:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityLagardereAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Date derniere opp Event">Dernière Opportunité Lagardère:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere.data}</b></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

If anyone can enlighten me about how to optimize this would be awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect what was meant by "anonymous apex class" was a return object that holds all the various values you need. Some people call these "wrapper" classes, whereas if it doesn't specifically wrap an SObject I call it a "data object" class. Anyway, as an example:

```
public class SyntheseData {
    @AuraEnabled
    Decimal aboAmount { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    Deimal placesSechesAmount { get; set; }

    ...

    public SyntheseData(Decimal aboAmount, Decimal placesSechesAmount, ...) {
        this.aboAmount = aboAmount;
        this.placesSechesAmount = placesSechesAmount;
        ...
    }
}
```

You can then write a single method to get the entire set of data in one go:

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static SyntheseData getSyntheseData(Id accountId) {
    Decimal aboAmount = ...; // Perhaps call the function you already have, or do this inline
    Decimal placesSechesAmount = ...; // etc.
    ...

    return new SyntheseData(aboAmount, placesSechesAmount, ...);
}
```

Your LWC can then get all the data with one wire:

```
import getSyntheseData from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getSyntheseData';

...
@wire(getSyntheseData, { accountId: '$recordId'}) syntheseData;
```

And you can access the details in your template, like:

```
<dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Something"><b>{syntheseData.data.aboAmount}</b></dd>
```

Note that there is no such thing as anonymous classes in Apex. Also note that your data object class can be made an inner class of your "controller" unless you want to pass an instance of the class to a wire or imperative Apex method otherwise you *might* get errors at runtime (something we saw in certain cases) - to avoid the errors you can make it a top level class.

Comment: Here's an example of how it can be done: https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/ProductController.cls

Comment: Just to be sure and i hope it’s note a stupid question. But i keep my apex class with all my SOQL requests then i import it to this new Apex Class SyntheseData right?

Comment: Typically you keep the SOQLs in the current class and use these to populate the properties of the data object, like I show with the local variables in getSyntheseData

Comment: Hi, i tried to realise what you told me but i have some issues i will post under